# I am trying to split an arithmetic equation into a list of terms and operators

Tags: python

An examples of what im trying to do:

```
split('2.1     * -5    + 3    ^ 2 +     1 +    -4.45')
```

should output

```
[2.1,'*',-5.0,'+',3.0,'^',2.0,'+',1.0,'+',-4.45]
```

my current code:

```
ops = ('+','-','*','/','^','(')

def split(txt):
    final = []
    temp = []
    inp = "".join(txt.split())
    for x in inp:
        if x.isdigit():
            temp.append(int(x))
        elif x == '.':
            temp.append(x)
        elif x in ops:
            if x == '-':
                if len(temp) == 0:
                    if isinstance(final[-1],float):
                        final.append(float("".join(temp)))
                        final.append(x)
                        temp = []
                    else:
                        temp.append(x)
                else:
                    final.append(float("".join(temp)))
                    final.append(x)
                    temp = []
            else:
                final.append("".join(temp))
                final.append(x)
                temp = []
    final.append(float("".join(temp)))
    print(final)
```

error, im not sure what im doing wrong here, and im not even sure if the code ive written is able to do what i want

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sahil Prusti\Desktop\cmpsc132\HW 3\hwtest.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(split('2* (       -5.2 + 3 ) ^2+ ( 1 +4 )'))
  File "C:\Users\Sahil Prusti\Desktop\cmpsc132\HW 3\hwtest.py", line 26, in split
    final.append("".join(temp))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

Comment: You have `temp.append(int(x))`.  You do not want the `int` call in there, you want it to stay a string.  `temp.append(x)`.

Comment: Do the splitting first, and then look for items to convert to float. Write a simple function to process a single token (either converting or leaving the original string), and apply it to the entire list.

Comment: Also: please use tags to characterize the *problem you are asking about, not* the overall task you need to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
s= '2.1     * -5    + 3    ^ 2 +     1 +    -4.45'

splitted = [x for x in s.split(' ') if x !=""]

result = []

for x in splitted:
    try:
         result.append(float(x))
    except ValueError:
        result.append(x)
      
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

In line 32, you split the string.

```
print(split('2* (       -5.2 + 3 ) ^2+ ( 1 +4 )'))
```

But what you are appending in line 26 is int, not string therefore, you have an error.

```
final.append("".join(temp))
```

try

```
final.append("".join(str(temp)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what is wrong with your program but you could reduce its complexity:

```
expr = '2.1     * -5    + 3    ^ 2 +     1 +    -4.45'

ops = ('+','-','*','/','^','(')

terms = expr.split()
print([float(t) if t not in ops else t for t in terms])
#[2.1, '*', -5.0, '+', 3.0, '^', 2.0, '+', 1.0, '+', -4.45]
```

For more sophisticated expressions a regular expression approach could be helpful.